# Visual Studio 2012 / Resharper / Found cool shortcut but can't reproduce

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

I just accidentally hit a cool shortcut (had a muffin in left hand while typing :-) ) but can't reproduce it. Even google has no answer.

I was in a comment line and suddenly the current time was printed out: "[26.11.2012 09:49  <-]"

Resharper 7.1 is installed, too.

Does someone know what I hit?

Comment: Do you have any other extensions installed? What kind of muffin was it? You probably need to eat another one to see if it jogs your memory.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Found it:

"STRG+1" is the solution. But I don't know where it comes from.

Better solution: 
Define a template in Reharper which dynamicly prints current username and current time.

Comment: I'm surprised. *Ctrl+1* is *Go To Bookmark 1* in default Visual Studio keyboard schema.

Comment: But that doesn't include the muffin extension :)  May be have a look in the Visual Studio options to see what that keyboard shortcut is mapped to. Or maybe you have some old macro that does it for you.

Comment: I meant **ReSharper**'s default Visual Studio keyboard schema.

Comment: Piers Myers comment in more detail: Go to *Tools->Options--->Environment->Keyboard*. Click in textbox "Press shortcut keys:" and press *Ctrl* and *1*. Then you see the key mapping in combobox "Shortcut currently used by:".